# Clicking RadioButton "A" toggles RadioButton "B" RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, radio-button, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView that displays a list of RadioButtons of countries, to let the user choose his country. I don't want more than on Item clicked, so I've wrote this OnCheckListener in the onBindView method of the adapter, but whenever I click a RadioButton, several other buttons toggles with it.

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final com.example.ameer.ta7adialma3rifa.adapters.CountriesAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        String name = mData.get(position).getName();
        int imgId = mData.get(position).getImageId();
        holder.radioButton.setText(name);
        holder.flagImageView.setImageResource(imgId);
        holder.radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                RadioButton button = (RadioButton) compoundButton;
                if (!button.getText().equals(mData.get(position).getName())){
                    button.setChecked(false);
                }
                if (runnable != null){
                    runnable.run();
                }
                runnable = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        holder.radioButton.setChecked(false);
                    }
                };
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: what is the use of runnable ??

Comment: Remove the Runnable. Since your `holder.radioButton.setChecked(false);` runs on Runnable, it messes with the  recyclerview item's position.

Comment: The runnable is used to uncheck the previous checked button, so when I click a button, it will uncheck the one selected before, to limit the checked buttons to one at a time.

Comment: It will not work as you expected. Try to run a for-loop and remove the checked state of other items.

Comment: I don't understand your logic. But remember that viewholder reuses view. For example if your 4th radioButton was checked after some intervals your next radioButton also will be checked. Be carefull in if statements in viewholder. if you put an if statement then put else statement also.

Comment: This is the problem actually, I think I shouldn't use RecyclerView in this case, I need to find another way.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your radio buttons in a radio group. this way just one of them is being chosen. and I don't know why are using runnable to set the radio button checked! I hope this helps you.

Comment: Actually I need to use the recyclerView because there is a lot of countries and if use RadioGroup it will lead to outOfMemoryExeption